# How do you refer to multiple columns in the function of an R dplyr mutate_at / mutate_if with an ifelse?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set with many columns from multiple sources, and I would like to unite each set of columns into a single column per set using `mutate_at` in `dplyr`, based on the condition in another column.  Here's an example of what I want, using hardcoded column names and `dplyr::mutate`:

```
library (dplyr)
library (tibble)
library (magrittr)

data <- tribble(
  ~source,    ~stars_1  ,  ~stars_2 ,  ~dashes_1  ,  ~dashes_2  , 
  "1"    ,    "*"       ,  "-"      ,  "-"        ,  "#"        , 
  "2"    ,    "+"       ,  "*"      ,  "+"        ,  "-"        , 
  "2"    ,    "+"       ,  "*"      ,  "+"        ,  "-"        
)      

dataClean <- data %>% 
  mutate (stars_1 = ifelse (source == 1, stars_1, stars_2),
          dashes_1 = ifelse (source == 1, dashes_1, dashes_2)) %>% 
  mutate (stars_Check = stars_1 == "*",
          dashes_Check = dashes_1 == "-")
```

I'm attempting to do this programatically, but it's not providing the desired result.

```
baseColNames <- c("stars", "dashes")

data %>% 
  mutate_at (.cols = paste0(baseColNames, "_1"), 
             .funs = funs(ifelse (source == 1, paste0(., "_1"), paste0(., "_2"))))
```

I'd prefer to do this in `dplyr` and `mutate_at` for ease of understanding by others.  Also, the data set is very large, so I would prefer not to `gather` and `spread` and/or use an `lapply`, which from prior experience would likely achieve the goal but at the expense of runtime.

Appreciate the help.

---

Update: Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62556564/refer-to-column-names-dynamically-inside-mutate-statements-dplyr).  Asks the same question.

Comment: Check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62556564/refer-to-column-names-dynamically-inside-mutate-statements-dplyr) where a similar issue is discussed. All the answerers suggest that it might not be possible to use the scoped variants of `mutate`, but a `tidyr` approach is suggested. `gather` and `spread` will be replaced by the new, more efficient `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider`. Would they be ok as an answer?

Comment: Thanks @RicS that post is asking the same question.   I will refer to that one for how to deal with this issue and try the new versions of the `pivot_` functions.