# Refer to column names dynamically inside mutate statements - dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, across

I stat apologize for the long question, but after quite a while I couldn't figure out a solution myself.

I have this toy dataframe

```
set.seed(23)
df <- tibble::tibble(
  id = paste0("00", 1:6),
  cond = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
  A_1 = sample(0:9, 6, replace = TRUE), A_2 = sample(0:9, 6, replace = TRUE), A_3 = sample(0:9, 6, replace = TRUE),
  B_1 = sample(0:9, 6, replace = TRUE), B_2 = sample(0:9, 6, replace = TRUE), B_3 = sample(0:9, 6, replace = TRUE),
  C_1 = sample(0:9, 6, replace = TRUE), C_2 = sample(0:9, 6, replace = TRUE), C_3 = sample(0:9, 6, replace = TRUE)
)

# A tibble: 6 x 11
#   id     cond   A_1   A_2   A_3   B_1   B_2   B_3   C_1   C_2   C_3
#   <chr> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 001       1     6     3     9     5     0     5     6     0     6
# 2 002       1     4     5     0     8     5     0     1     6     6
# 3 003       2     4     2     8     8     8     6     5     2     5
# 4 004       2     4     4     0     7     2     6     7     5     7
# 5 005       3     1     7     0     9     9     0     5     7     8
# 6 006       3     3     8     7     0     2     5     0     9     4
```

I would like to create three variables `A_def`, `B_def`, `C_def` that take the values of only one of the corresponding variables <*LETTER_NUMBER*> depending on the condition that their suffix is equal to variable `cond`.

For instance, for the rows where `cond == 1`, `A_def` should have values from `A_1`, `B_def` should have values from `B_1`, `C_def` should have values from `C_1`. Likewise, if `cond == 2`, the `*_def` columns should have values from the respective `*_2` variables.

I managed to achieve my desired output in two ways: one hard-coded (possibly to avoid if `cond` contains many values) and one using `tidyr`'s pivoting functions.

Hard-coded solution:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    A_def = ifelse(cond == 1, A_1, ifelse(cond == 2, A_2, A_3)),
    B_def = ifelse(cond == 1, B_1, ifelse(cond == 2, B_2, B_3)),
    C_def = ifelse(cond == 1, C_1, ifelse(cond == 2, C_2, C_3))
  ) %>% 
  select(id, cond, contains("_def"))
```

`tidyr`'s solution:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("_")) %>% 
  mutate(
    number = gsub("[A-Za-z_]", "", name),
    name = gsub("[^A-Za-z]", "", name)
  ) %>% 
  filter(cond == number) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(id, cond), names_from = name, values_from = value, names_glue = "{name}_def")
```

Output in both cases

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
#   id     cond A_def B_def C_def
#   <chr> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 001       1     6     5     6
# 2 002       1     4     8     1
# 3 003       2     2     8     2
# 4 004       2     4     2     5
# 5 005       3     0     0     8
# 6 006       3     7     5     4
```

---

Now, I was wondering whether it is possible to obtain the same output using `mutate` and/or `across` in a dynamic fashion (maybe using `ifelse` statements inside `mutate`?). I tried the following code snippets but the results were not as expected. In one of them I tried to make the variable names as symbols within `ifelse` statements, but I got an error.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(paste0(c("A", "B", "C"), "_1"),
                ~ifelse(cond == 1, cur_column(), 
                        ifelse(cond == 2, cur_column(), paste0(gsub("[^A-Za-z]", "", cur_column()), "_3"))))) %>% 
  select(id, cond, contains("_1"))

df %>% 
  mutate_at(paste0(c("A", "B", "C"), "_1"),
            ~ifelse(cond == 1, ., ifelse(cond == 2, ., paste0(., "_2")))) %>% 
  select(id, cond, contains("_1"))

df %>% 
  mutate_at(paste0(c("A", "B", "C"), "_1"),
            ~ifelse(cond == 1, !!!rlang::syms(paste0(c("A", "B", "C"), "_1")),
                    ifelse(cond == 2, !!!rlang::syms(paste0(c("A", "B", "C"), "_2")),
                           !!!rlang::syms(paste0(c("A", "B", "C"), "_3")))))
```

Question: is there a way to obtain the same desired output as above using `dplyr`'s statements such as `mutate` (or its superseded scoped variants) and/or `across`?

Comment: I think your `tidyr` solution is the standard way to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: As @RonakShah says, it's not obvious what a more generic solution than your `tidyr` solution would be.  [As an aside, it could be made a little more elegant by using `names_sep` in `pivot_longer`...]

Comment: Thank you for your opinions, I didn't know if there was also a simple way using `mutate` or I was just looking for dark matter..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the other comments that `tidyr` makes for more readable code, but here's an alternative approach with `pmap`:

```
library(purrr)
library(rlang)
pmap_dfr(df, ~with(list(...), 
               set_names(c(id, cond, 
                           map_dbl(c("A","B","C"),
                                 ~ eval_tidy(parse_expr(paste(.x,cond,sep = "_"))))),
                          c("id","cond","A_def","B_def","C_def"))
               ))
# A tibble: 6 x 5
     id  cond A_def B_def C_def
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     6     5     6
2     2     1     4     8     1
3     3     2     2     8     2
4     4     2     4     2     5
5     5     3     0     0     8
6     6     3     7     5     4
```

Comment: I have to study it as I'm not very familiar with purrr, but it's probably one of the best non-tidyr solution! Maybe my "using `mutate`" idea is too difficult to implement, and also non-advisable

Answer (score 2):

As Ronak said, your `tidyr` solution seems quite fine.

You can simplify it a bit though:

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("_"), names_to = c("name", "number"), names_sep = "_") %>% 
  filter(cond == number) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(id, cond), names_glue = "{name}_def")


## A tibble: 6 x 5
#  id     cond A_def B_def C_def
#  <chr> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
#1 001       1     7     8     1
#2 002       1     2     5     2
#3 003       2     4     2     3
#4 004       2     0     3     1
#5 005       3     9     0     7
#6 006       3     9     7     0
```

Comment: Thank you for the `names_to` simplification, didn't think about it!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short base R solution using `mapply`:

```
f <- function(x, i) df[-(1:2)][i, c(x, x+3, x+6)]
df <- cbind(df[1:2], t(mapply(f, df$cond, seq(nrow(df)))))
setNames(df, c("id", "cond", "A_def", "B_def", "C_def"))
#>    id cond A_def B_def C_def
#> 1 001    1     7     8     1
#> 2 002    1     2     5     2
#> 3 003    2     4     2     3
#> 4 004    2     0     3     1
#> 5 005    3     9     0     7
#> 6 006    3     9     7     0
```